# How to create design Android using recyclerView with dynamic item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout

I want to make an Android design with Kotlin like this.How do I create a design like that with recyclerView? If you scroll, the bottom display will be like the design example above too.

[sample design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN13w.png)

please help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager) when you build your RecyclerView. It automatically lays things out in a similar manner, generally granting views the space they need no matter their size and shape.

Comment: Can you give me the code, I've looked it up but still don't understand